# Show total number of selected filters array of items in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures, react-hooks

I have the following problem. In widgetFilters array (length===3) i want to show the numbers of selected items in the header of the Filter.

```
  const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilters] = useState([]);
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In code snipet below i map through all the widgetFilter array and making 3 Accordion with the headline the name typeName of filter and then the options that filter contains e.g.

```
      <Stack>
        {widgetFilters.map((filter) => (
          <FilterWidgetAccordion
            key={filter.id}
            headline={filter.typeName}
            list={filter.options}
            selectedFilters={selectedFilters}
            setSelectedFilters={setSelectedFilters}
          />
        ))}
      </Stack>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**FilterWidgetAccordion.js**

```
    <Fragment>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
          <StyledTypography>{headline}</StyledTypography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          {list?.map((filterItem) => {
            return(
        
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                const list = [...selectedFilters];
                const index = list.indexOf(filterItem);
                index === -1 ? list.push(filterItem) : list.splice(index, 1);
                setSelectedFilters(list);
              }}
              key={filterItem.value}
            >
              {filterItem.value} 
            </Button>
          )})}
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </Fragment>
```

I want next to e.g "Product Category" title to add the number of selected buttons look the image below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate filters for each widget then display filters length in the headline, here is an example :

```
  const updateWidgetFilters=(myFilters, widgetTypeId)=>{
    setSelectedFilters((prevSelectedFilters)=>{
      const selectedElement = prevSelectedFilters?.find(({typeId})=>typeId===widgetTypeId);
      if(selectedElement) {
        selectedElement.filters= myFilters;
        return [...prevSelectedFilters]
      }
      return [...prevSelectedFilters, {typeId: widgetTypeId, filters: myFilters}]; 
    });
  }
```

...

```
  <Stack>
    {widgetFilters.map((filter) => (
      <FilterWidgetAccordion
        key={filter.id}
        headline={
              filter.typeName+' '
              +(selectedFilters?.find(({typeId})=>typeId===filter.typeId)?.filters?.length || 0)
        }
        list={filter.options}
        selectedFilters={selectedFilters?.find(({widgetId})=>typeId===filter.typeId)?.filters || []}
        setSelectedFilters={(filters)=>updateWidgetFilters(filters, filter.typeId)}
      />
    ))}
  </Stack>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..i received a message "ReferenceError: prevData is not defined" at the second return statement any ideas?

Comment: I tested the code locally with different variables names when I changed the vars names I forgot prevData, but I edit the vars names now.